# Ruby on rails where() with a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to perform a where() query, on a method of a model. How to I do this?

If I can't, is there any way I can do this:

```
Session.find_each.select do |session|
  session.end_date > params[:date_from].to_date && session.end_date < params[:date_to].to_date
end
```

But returning an ActiveRecordRelation instead of an Array?

session.rb

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  delegate :units, to: :course

  def end_date
    start_date + units.count.weeks
  end
end
```

`end_date` is the method, but `start_date` is a field.

Comment: Try using scope in model see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html and   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: I don't see how this can help me.

Comment: `Session.where("end_date > ? and end_date < ?", params[:date_from].to_date, params[:date_to].to_date)` try this, this will give you those session whom end_date is between date_from to date_to, you can also optimise this query by give symbolic assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you'll have to use `joins`

`units` belongs to course, so you'll have to join `courses` table before applying `where`. Otherwise, your fetch all sessions, and filter one by one based on `end_date`, which will generate a lots sql queries.

```
Session.joins(:course).where("calculate_end_date() > ? AND calculated_end_date() < ?", date, date)
```

you'll need to `calculate end date` use sql functions, google it